# Creating a scatter plot with 4 or more data columns fails, whereas it works with only 3

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a CSV file that I'm importing into Excel. It's formatted like this:

```
 Time Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4  .. VarN 
   0    1    1    1    0   ..   0 
   1    1    0    1    0   ..   0 
   2    0    0    0    1   ..   0
```

I've discovered that I can quickly insert a Scatter Chart that looks perfect if I only select the Time and the first 3 Variables:

[image: 3 variable chart in excel]

However, if I select four or more Variables, it all goes wrong and assumes my rows are the data, not the Time!

[image: 4 variable chart in excel]

Comment: Just tested in Excel 2016 and it works as intended with any amount of columns. Can you paste screenshots?

Comment: Thanks Art Gertner.  it would seem I'm on 2010.  Maybe that's the issue... I'll see about the screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Produced in Excel 2016 with sample data arranged in 5 columnes:
[image]

Just clicked Insert > Scatter no additional tweaks. Excel has automatically recognized column names as series and time as X axis values. Tried with 3,4,5 and 6 columns - same results

It could be a disadvantage of older Excel version you are using.

Comment: Thanks @Art.  I think that is going to be it then.  It would also explain why my googling didn't find anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When there are more rows than columns, Excel plots series by column. So your first case, with three things, plots as expected. When there are more columns, Excel plots by row. When there are equal numbers of rows and columns, Excel should plot by column IMHO, but instead plots by row.

When you select five columns in your data range, it's six rows, but Excel sees five rows of numerical data, and plots by row. So your chart is broken.

But you can take the broken chart, go to the ribbon (the left-most tab under Chart Tools), and click Switch Rows and Columns. And your chart is back to the way you want it.